# Is there a way to get Bundle ID of current open app

Tags: iphone, ios5, theos

I'm using Theos to develop a jailbreak tweak, and I need to get the Bundle ID of the current open application. I'm modifying `SBBannerView.h` which is a SpringBoard header. I tried Using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
```

and also:

```
[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier
```

which should both give the bundle identifier of the app, but because I'm modifying the iOS Banner Notifications, I think it's always returning `com.apple.springboard` because thats the object calling the notifications

how would I get the application bundle ID of the current app that I have displaying on screen?

for Instance, if I have the Settings.app open, what would I hook or call to get the bundle ID `com.apple.Preferences`

I'm sorry if I didn't explain too well

Thank you for everyones help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, for anyone else who is trying to accomplish this:

```
SBApplication *frontApp = [(SpringBoard*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication];
NSString *currentAppDisplayID = [frontApp displayIdentifier];
```